# AES encryption in VB6 and Java

Tags: java, encryption, vb6, cryptography, aes

I am trying to encrypt data using AES in VB6, and match the same encryption in Java.  I took the basic VB6 code from Microsoft here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821762

**VB6:**

```
strProvider = "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider (Prototype)" &     vbNullChar  
lngHashType = CALG_MD5  
lngAlgoType = CALG_AES_128 
strPassword = "secretPassphrase"

If CBool(CryptAcquireContext(g_lngCryptoContext, ByVal strTemp, _
         ByVal strProvider, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT)) Then           
    GetProvider = True
else 
    GoTo CleanUp
End If

If Not CBool(CryptCreateHash(g_lngCryptoContext, lngHashType, ByVal 0&, _
             ByVal 0&, lngHashHnd)) Then

    MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptCreateHash!", _
           vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Encryption Errors"
    GoTo CleanUp
End If

If Not CBool(CryptHashData(lngHashHnd, strPassword, Len(strPassword), ByVal 0&)) Then
    MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptHashData!", _
           vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Encryption Errors"
    GoTo CleanUp
End If

If Not CBool(CryptDeriveKey(g_lngCryptoContext, lngAlgoType, _
             lngHashHnd, ByVal CRYPT_NO_SALT, lngkey)) Then

    MsgBox "Error: " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptDeriveKey!", _
           vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Encryption Errors"
    GoTo CleanUp
End If

If lngHashHnd <> 0 Then
    lngRetCode = CryptDestroyHash(lngHashHnd)
End If
lngHashHnd = 0

lngEncDataLength = Len(g_strInData)         
lngEnctBuffLen = lngEncDataLength * 2
strEncBuffer = String$(lngEnctBuffLen, vbNullChar)
LSet strEncBuffer = g_strInData

If Not CBool(CryptEncrypt(lngkey, ByVal 0&, ByVal 1&, ByVal 0&, _
                          strEncBuffer, lngEncDataLength, lngEnctBuffLen)) Then

    MsgBox "Bytes required:" & CStr(lngEnctBuffLen) & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
           "Error: " & CStr(GetLastError) & " during CryptEncrypt!", _
           vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly, "Encryption Errors"
    GoTo CleanUp
End If

strOutData = Mid$(strEncBuffer, 1, lngEncDataLength)
g_abytOutData = StringToByteArray(strOutData)
```

Mode, padding, iv, and block length are not explicitly set, but are CBC, PKCS5, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, and 128 respectively as are defaults and I have verified using the GetKeyParam function.

**JAVA:**

```
String password = "secretPassphrase";  
String text = "text to encrypt";  
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");  
md.update(password.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, password.length());  
byte[] rawKey = md.digest();  
byte[] iv = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};  
IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);  
SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");  
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "SunJCE");  
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, ivSpec);  
byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));  
System.out.println(toHex(encrypted));
```

Even though I've set the encryption settings the same on both sides, I get different results when I output the encryptions as hex. I am wondering if the 2 different CSPs are compatible using AES?

If I alter the code slightly on both ends to use RC2 instead of AES, the encryptions match.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. I am pulling my hair out on this one.

Comment: Why not post the actual VB code?

Comment: Does it need to be secure? And do you face active attackers who could modify a message? If yes, you'll need to replace both systems.

Comment: Thanks @GregS, I have posted the VB code.

Comment: Thanks @CodesInChaos, the end goal is to encrypt in VB, post to a Java web server and temporarily store, then decrypt on a private server. Can you expand on your comment please. Why would both systems need to be replaced?

Comment: Because its very likely that an attacker can use the recipient as a padding oracle to decrypt the message. And using a zero IV isn't a good idea either. Your password hash is too weak as well, unless the password is *really* strong. Use a salted iterated hash instead.

Comment: Thanks for you input @CodesInChaos. I can look into strengthening the encryption. At this point though I am still unable to get the encryptions to match using AES with the current, basic settings.

Comment: Does the java code or the vb6 code produce the correct output? For the input/password in your java code I show a correct output of A9EC372BC92C7C1A8F4A4981FC8BF5C7